# Jtable not populated for the one record

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I am working on the problem where i need to get data from the database and then populate in the jtable. I am using the Query with like statement. The problem is when query match with one record, i am not able to see any record in the table . Here is my code.

```
 ResultSet rs=null;
        String customer_name = null;
        System.out.println("In the verfiy login");
        try {
            Connect_MYSQL object = new Connect_MYSQL();
            conn = object.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while getting connection");
        }
        try {
            Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            String Query = "Select * from login where username like'%"+ name+"%' or usertype like'%"+name+"%'";
            System.out.println(Query);
             rs = statement.executeQuery(Query);
            if (rs.next()) {
           System.out.println("INsie Rs");

                return rs;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return rs;
```

and how i am using in JTABLE

```
   DataBase_Work object=new DataBase_Work();
        ResultSet rs2=object.Search_User(name);
        String namee=rs2.getString("username");
        System.out.println(namee+"User name");

        if(rs2==null)
        {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found Against the value", " Not Record Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
        }     
        else
        {
         Show_all_User.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
        }
```

Comment: A `ResultSet` is a series (or a "set") of results, you need to iterate of the `ResultSet` to get each individual row.  Have a look at [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you call `next()` on the `ResultSet` to check if it is not empty (before returning it), so the cursor will already be past the first record. If the set contains only one entry, the current row will be invalid and `getString` returns null.

Use `rs.first()` instead of `rs.next()` to check if the `ResultSet` is empty.

Comment: I have used rs.first() but still the result is same